# Drawing in a Window wx.clientDC is not relative to panel but to the whole window

Tags: wxpython, gdi

I'm using wxPython to build a Cut Optimizer for a project and I want to layout a simple frame for the drawing area, and a small panel underneath for actions and messages.

I'm doing this:

```
topPanel = wx.Panel(self)
# the intended drawing area, 800x600    
self.planeArea = wx.Window(topPanel, -1, pos=(0, 0), size=(800, 600))

# a panel for showing messages and placing some buttons    
commandArea = wx.Panel(topPanel, -1, pos=(800, 0), size=(800, 200))
button = wx.Button(commandArea, -1, label='Optimize')

box = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)        
box.Add(self.planeArea, 0, wx.EXPAND | wx.ALL)
box.Add(commandArea, 0, wx.EXPAND | wx.ALL)
topPanel.SetSizer(box)
```

And in my drawing method I do:

```
# I'm using clientDC because I draw the shapes after the user chooses a file, Am I doing it wrong? I still haven't figured how or when to use paintDC and left that research for later
dc = wx.ClientDC(self.planeArea)
dc.Clear()
dc.SetDeviceOrigin(0, 0)

for polygon in plane.polygons:
    dc.DrawPolygon(polygon.vertices)
```

If I don't use SetDeviceOrigin, the polygons are drawn from the leftmost and topmost point of the window, but I want to start from the leftmost, bottommost point.

The problem is that my drawings are misplaced because that 0,0 is relative to the whole window, and not to my drawing panel.

I've been reading the documentation and following examples but I can't sort this out. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

I'm using wxPython2.9-osx-cocoa-py2.7 in Mountain Lion and Python 2.7 (PyDev and Eclipse)

Many thanks,

Rod

Comment: So basically what I'm trying to do is to start drawing from the bottom, left vertex of the drawing area, where by default it starts from the top, left vertex. I'm sure this must be pretty simple but I must be missing something

Answer (score 0):

I usually leave the origin and such alone and adjust the drawing instead, but I think you want something like `dc.SetDeviceOrigin(0, dc.GetSize().height-1)`, meaning that point (0,height-1) in the default coordinate space is to be the new (0,0).  However the coordinates above that point will still be negative and positive below that.  To switch that around you need to call `SetAxisOrientation`.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what is wrong but I have the same problem.

I figured out that if you use wx.ClientDC(event.GetEventObject()) and put your method outside, it works fine on osx (10.6.8 python 2.7 wxpython 2.9.4.0 cocoa)

This works relatively (draw a frame and a panel then a box relative to the panel):

```
import wx

class test(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(test, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.InitUI()
    def InitUI(self):
        panel = wx.Panel(self, -1)
        graphpanel = wx.Panel(panel, -1, pos=(50, 50), size=(200, 200))
        graphpanel.Bind(wx.EVT_PAINT, PaintGraph)
        self.SetSize ((1000,750))
        self.Centre()
        self.Show(True)

def PaintGraph(event):
    graph = wx.ClientDC(event.GetEventObject())
    graph.SetPen(wx.Pen(wx.BLUE, 1, wx.SOLID))
    graph.DrawRectangle(0, 0, 100, 100)

def main():
    ex = wx.App()
    test(None)
    ex.MainLoop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

This works relatively on windows but not osx (on my OSX 10.6.8 it draws on the frame):

```
import wx

class test(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(test, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.InitUI()
    def InitUI(self):
        panel = wx.Panel(self, -1)
        graphpanel = wx.Panel(panel, -1, pos=(50, 50), size=(200, 200))
        graphpanel.Bind(wx.EVT_PAINT, self.PaintGraph)
        self.SetSize ((1000,750))
        self.Centre()
        self.Show(True)    
    def PaintGraph(self, event):
        graph = wx.ClientDC(self)
        graph.SetPen(wx.Pen(wx.BLUE, 1, wx.SOLID))
        graph.DrawRectangle(0, 0, 100, 100)

def main():
    ex = wx.App()
    test(None)
    ex.MainLoop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Anyone knows why?